# Google maps API - moving inline json to external file

Tags: jquery, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to move my inline json to an external file and pull it in.

This is my json which is currently inline.

```
var locations = [

    [40.902, -74.407, 'Dial-a-Ride', 'Boonton Town', '973-402-9410, ext. 631' ],
    [40.933,-74.425, 'Dial-a-Ride', 'Boonton Township', '973-331-3336'],
    [40.999497, -74.346326, 'Dial-a-Ride', 'Butler Borough', '973-835-8885'],
    [40.7372, -74.4253, 'Dial-a-Ride', 'Chatham Boro and Chatham Township', '973-635-4565'],
    [40.785999, -74.692904, 'Dial-a-Ride', 'Chester Borough and Chester Township', '908-876-9496'],
    [40.892222, -74.4775, 'Dial-a-Ride', 'Denville Township', '973-625-7799'],


    [40.902857, -74.407712, 'American Legion', 'Boonton Post', '210 Main St.<br>Boonton, NJ 07005'],
    [41.00276744260799, -74.35810804367065, 'American Legion', 'John A. Dean Post', '15 Kiel Ave.<br>Butler, NJ 07403'],
    [40.73794, -74.38449, 'American Legion', 'Chatham Post', 'Box 11<br>Chatham, NJ 07928'],
    [40.78721, -74.68885, 'American Legion', 'Bernays Apgar Post', 'P.O. Box 342<br>Chester, NJ 07930'],
    [40.894537669741894, -74.48481559753418, 'American Legion', 'Denville Memorial Post', 'Legion Place<br>Denville, NJ 07834'],
    [40.88243629753742, -74.56002473831177, 'American Legion', 'William H. Baker Post', '2 Legion Place<br>Dover, NJ 07801'],


    [40.903020287948806, -74.40771818161011, 'Veterans of Foreign Wars', 'Boonton Post #242', '221 Main St.<br>Boonton, NJ 07005'],
    [40.91534490699327, -74.48998689651489, 'Veterans of Foreign Wars', 'Denville Post #2519', '71 Ford Rd.<br>Denville, NJ 07834', 'Veterans of Foreign Wars'],
    [40.82603680244624, -74.42166566848755, 'Veterans of Foreign Wars', 'Hanover Post #5351', '750 State Route 10<br>Hanover Twp., NJ 07981', 'Veterans of Foreign Wars'],
    [40.87683907004174, -74.63418245315552, 'Veterans of Foreign Wars', 'Kenvil Post #2833', '16 High St.<br>Kenvil, NJ 07847', 'Veterans of Foreign Wars'],
    [40.88654063021766, -74.36521053314209, 'Veterans of Foreign Wars', 'Montville Post #5481', '132 Change Bridge Rd.<br>Montville, NJ 07045', 'Veterans of Foreign Wars'],
    [40.83861926691208, -74.58420753479004, 'Veterans of Foreign Wars', 'Mt. Freedom Post #7333', 'Carrell Rd.<br>Mt. Freedom, NJ 07970', 'Veterans of Foreign Wars'],


    [40.83020957464309, -74.5130968093872, 'Nutrition', 'Morris Mews', 'Dean Gallo Congregate Housing, 99 Ketch Rd.<br>(973) 540-8063; open Monday through Friday'],
    [40.80247276179082, -74.48412895202637, 'Nutrition', 'Morristown', 'Wetmore Towers, 31 Early St.<br>(973) 644-0343; open Monday through Friday'],
    [40.896905775860006, -74.69329833984375, 'Nutrition', 'Mt. Olive Township', 'Mt. Olive Senior Center, 204 Flanders-Drakestown Rd.<br>(973) 448-7474; open Monday, Wednesday, Friday'],
    [40.87304242027383, -74.39115285873413, 'Nutrition', 'Parsippany', 'Parsippany Community Center, 1130 Knoll Rd.<br>(973) 884-1868; open Monday through Friday'],
    [40.901593078403536, -74.52371835708618, 'Nutrition', 'Rockaway', 'Pleasant View Village, 221 Mt. Pleasant Ave.<br>(973) 361-9376; open Tuesday, Wednesday, Friday'],
    [40.8563177, -74.637607, 'Nutrition', 'Roxbury Township', 'Roxbury Senior Center, 72 Eyland Avenue<br>(973) 361-5231; open Wednesday and Friday']
];
```

Here is the marker loop:

```
// Looping through the JSON data
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

    // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
        map: map,
        title: locations[i][3],
        icon: iconSrc[locations[i][2]]
    });
    markers.push(marker);


    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(locations[i][3] + "<br />" + locations[i][4]);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));

}// END for loop
```

What i want to know is after i pull in the json with jQuery's getJSON() how do i then get the values of into the correct paramters.
If you think the json is better setup with keys and values let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just create an external javascript file with that content and just include it in your page, that would be the simplest solution.

Comment: Would i just put the getJSON() into a variable called locations or something for it to work?

Comment: You don't need the getJSON call.  Put your locations variable definition in the external file (say "locations.js"), include that file in the head of your html file, then access it the way you do now.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Didn't realise i could do that! Thanks so much!